# Copy file from CI Pipeline to Azure Devops Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a pipeline and want to copy a file after being processed in the pipeline onto Azure devops reposirory. 
I used [cURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/curl-upload-files?view=azure-devops) to copy as per the setting below. But still can not copy.

What job can I use to copy files?

[image: Setting of cURL]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Copy file from CI Pipeline to Azure Devops Repository

If your repo is git repo, you could use the git command line to commit and push the file back to the repo.

Details:

Add a command line task in the pipeline to use git command line to clone repo:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

git clone <repo> <directory>
```

We use the copy task to copy the `docs.zip` file to the `<directory>` folder.

Then add a command line task to submit and push the changes to the repo:

```
git commit -m "Add docs.zip file"

git push -u origin master
```

Note: When you use git clone   to clone the repo, you need to provide your certificate in your source link, usually using PAT:

[image]

The link looks like:

```
https://<OrganizationName>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

Then we need to replace the first OrganizationName with PAT. So, it will be:

```
https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case of this upload?
An Azure Repo is meant for code storage not data.
You could publish your files as an artifact and have a different pipeline to consume.

If it is for storage purposes I suggest using azure blob storage or something

Comment: Simply the file after being created by  [Jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/) . 
I want to copy to the Azure Devops Repository, not azure blob storage.
Is there any way?

Comment: Then you have to 'commit' the file, because it is a got repo. You can use rest api for that.

Answer (score 0):

@Leo Liu-MSFT
Thanks you sir .
I used this scrips and it ran .

```
git config --global user.email "yourname@email.com"
git config --global user.name "yourname"

git status

git checkout xxxbranch


git add $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/doc/Jsdoc.zip 
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/doc/coverage.zip


git status

git commit -m "Latest JsDoc Version"

git push origin xxxbranch
```