# How to Automatically upload a file to Azure DevOps repository through a release pipeline CMD task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline in Azure devops to generate the .dacpac file using CMD task in release pipeline. The .dacpac file is getting generated successfully when I am giving \tf: path as $(Agent.HomeDirectory). I want to give path of the folder in my repository where I would like to save the .dacpac file.

Below is the command which I tried to store the file on (Agent.HomeDirectory) and it runs fine.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin>sqlpackages.exe /Action:Extract /ssn:tcp:,1433 /sdn: /su: /sp: /tf:$(Agnet.HomeDirectory)/test.dacpac /p:Storage=File**

Please guide me how we can store the file to repository folder from command line.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps:

1. I created a release pipeline and added this repo: testproject, branch: test
   [image]
2. Add CMD task, the script is as follows:

   cd D:\a\r1\a_testproject

   cd . > 001.txt // I create a test txt here. Please copy the file you need to the path. Or you can to use git to clone a repo in the path you want.

   git config --global user.email "xxxx@mail.com"

   git config --global user.name "xxxx"

   git status

   git add -A

   git status

   git commit -m "Latest updated"
   git show-ref

   git push -u origin HEAD:test  //if the push step show the error: src refspec xxxx does not match any.  please check the log and choose a rignt head

[image]

3. Allow scripts to access the OAuth token
   [image]
4. set permission of the account `{projectname} Build Service (orgname)`
   [image]

For more info ,please refer [Copy file from CI Pipeline to Azure Devops Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455288/copy-file-from-ci-pipeline-to-azure-devops-repository) and [How to add/update files in git repository from Azure DevOps Pipeline Dynamics 365 CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680490/how-to-add-update-files-in-git-repository-from-azure-devops-pipeline-dynamics-36).